# Call Function By Result Of Another Function In PHP

Tags: php, function, return-value

How Can I Call a Function By Result Of Another Function?
For Example `users()` Function return All My Users And I Want To Get User Posts With `$user->posts()`.

For Example :

```
foreach (users() as $user){
    $user->posts();
}
```

How Can I Do It?

Comment: your code is enough to call

Comment: Veshraj Joshi, i did not write any code. I want to write but I do not know how.

Comment: Your example is a __correct code__, use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example was exactly what you need. This is the full example:

```
class user {
        function post() {
                // Do what ever you want here
        }
}

function getUser() {
        return array(new user(),new user());
}

foreach(getUser() as $user)
        $user->post();
```

This is the PHP syntax